# How to optimize adding components to a view?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

First of all, I have about 1000-1500 records and I need to show them in a grid in custom style. But, first row has to contain checkbox and a form(combo,textfield), which is below that checkbox.
Similar to:

```
row1: checkbox
      combo, textfield, textfield
row2: checkbox
      combo, textfield, textfield
...
```

So, I could not use grid for this approach(Because I have to use 'colum render function' to each row and it causes re-render whole grid again even if change one row).

That's why I tried to add each component to a panel dynamically. But the main problem is that whenever I add the components to the panel, it takes too long . For example, it takes 4.5 s for only 100 records. I can't even imagine how long would it take for 1500 records.

Please check this fiddle. You will understand the exact problem. please do not forget the check console.time:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13g0

And sample codes:

```
console.time('FakeGrid');
        Ext.suspendLayouts();
        var fakeGrid = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Fake grid Panel',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        });



        var records = [];
        for(var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            records.push({
                id: 'Check'+ i,
                reg: 'Reg' + i
            })
        }

        Ext.each(records, function(rec) {
            var regionPanel = {
              xtype: 'fieldset',
              collapsible: true,
              border: false,
              title: rec.reg,
              layout: 'vbox',
              items: []
            };
            Ext.each(records, function(rec) {
                var hBoxPanel = {
                  xtype: 'panel',
                  layout: 'hbox',
                  items: [{
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    boxLabel: rec.id
                  }]
                };
                var fakeSubPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        fieldLabel: 'Combo'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'field1'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'field2'
                    }] 
                });
                var sitePanel = {
                  xtype: 'panel',
                  layout: 'vbox',
                  //margin: '5 0 0 31',
                  items: [hBoxPanel, fakeSubPanel]
                };
                regionPanel.items.push(sitePanel);
            }); //Ext.each
            fakeGrid.add(regionPanel);
        }); //Ext.each

        Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
        console.timeEnd('FakeGrid');
```

If you have any suggestion, please enlight me with your ideas. Thank you so much!

Comment: Seems like a UX problem :-)

Comment: could be part of a UX problem. But,  when I put those records to grid, it's rendering within couple of seconds :) Should be better way or I am doing something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: Grid is faster while it doesn't render all records, it renders only "visible" records. I didn't really understand the problem in using grid? Why you should use rendere? You can use widgetcolumn for these purposes.

Comment: something like this https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13i2

Comment: avoid using nested loop cycles

Comment: @yorlin sorry for late response. I had to implement your approach to my actual grid. It worked when I use widgetcolumn. Please post your reply as an answer :) As for what's wrong with grid in my case, I used renderer in columns and whenever I change any row, whole grid was rendering again instead of only one row. That's why I couldn't use grid for this approach. Anyway  thank you for reply!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest , Nested loops do not take too long time. Could you explain more why I should avoid nested loop cycles if possible? Thanks.

Comment: @SemihGk., consider this post: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/199196/why-are-nested-loops-considered-bad-practice